# C++ Struct pointer question

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

This is probably simple, but im trying to try and understand pointers better.
Lets say I have a struct

```
struct Person{
  char Name[20];
  char ID[15];
  char Address[50];
  char Number[15];
};
```

and lets say I have a bunch of these stored in memory like one after the other.
so now i declare a new pointer to the struct.

```
struct Person *ptr;
```

Will this Pointer start at the FIRST entry? (aka the first "Name") and when I iterate it (aka ptr++) will it go to the next STRUCT or the next "entry" aka like name-->ID--->Address

So lets say Im on the first entry for example and the data is:

```
Jason Adams
111222333
111 Fake Drive
55555551000
```

and the second entry is

```
Matt Johns
111555333
555 Derp lane
1000022434
```

now I iterate the ptr  (ptr++) will the ptr point to second struct (the one with matt johns) or will it point to Jason Adams "ID"

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will point to the second struct. The pointer will be advanced by `sizeof(Person)`.

Comment: Oh so if I wanted to get to the next entry i'd use ptr+sizeof(Person)? or does it "know" to go to the second struct when just using ptr++

Comment: No. Whenever you add an integral value to a pointer it implicitly multiplies the value by `sizeof(<pointed-to type>)`. If you add 1 to a pointer (either by `ptr++` or `ptr + n`), it implicitly advances "one of the pointed-to element." If you added `sizeof(Person)` to a `Person*`, it would advance way more than one entry.

Comment: OH gotcha, thanks. thats what I thought it was but wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

As John mentioned, it will be advanced by the size of itself - aka sizeof(Person).

Pointer manipulation is fun however, and you can do things like cast the pointer to a different type.  Once you do that, pointer arithmetic will advance by the underlying size of the type.  Commonly you'll see pointers casted to (byte *) or (unsigned char *) to allow individual byte access to the underlying data.

Comment: Interesting, well lets say you wanted to advance the ptr to point to Jason Adams "ID" (i dunno why you'd want to) but just out of curiosity how would you go about doing that?

Comment: You can't legally do that and still have a pointer to a Person, because `char [15]` is not the same type as `Person`.

Comment: Then what did he mean when he said "cast a pointer to a different type", sorry im not the best with pointers :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must allocate memory for your pointer ptr before using it.

```
auto_ptr<Person> ptr(new Person); //auto_ptr for automatic freeing
```

After that, you can try below code.

```
strcpy(ptr->ID, "100"); //For illustraction
int offset = ptr->ID - ptr->Name; //Get offset of ID member
char *pID = ((char *)ptr.get())+ offset;
//Typecast to char pointer and increment by offset to get to ID field
cout<<pID; //Now pId can be used to access ID.
```

You asked how to access ID attribute by incrementing ptr.

As shown above, you can access ID member of structure.

Comment: You should not use `auto_ptr`, it is deprecated in C++0x.

Comment: @Adam: ya, i know. But OP tagged as c++